# Tastypie: REST API where POST and GET resource format are different

Tags: rest, tastypie

I've created an API. GETting my resource gives:

```
{
    category: {
        id: "517ed1bff929f90e1152ad43",
        name: "Test category"
    },
    cost: "Free",
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tincidunt augue in mi scelerisque quis condimentum velit sollicitudin. Nam eleifend posuere semper. Pellentesque non nulla et arcu ornare lacinia. Donec quis dui at velit placerat volutpat vitae sit amet lorem. ",
    genders: [
        "M",
        "F"
    ],
    id: "517ed1bff929f90e1152ad44",
    tags: [
        {
            id: "517ed1bff929f90e1152ad3f",
            name: "testing",
            resource_uri: "/api/v1/interests/517ed1bff929f90e1152ad3f/"
        },
        {
            id: "517ed1bff929f90e1152ad41",
            name: "coding",
            resource_uri: "/api/v1/interests/517ed1bff929f90e1152ad41/"
        }
    ],
    location: {
        lat_lng: [
            51.500705,
            -0.124575
        ],
        locality: "London",
        name: "Big Ben"
    },
    resource_uri: "/api/v1/events/517ed1bff929f90e1152ad44/",
    slug: "test-event1",
    title: "Test event1"
}
```

I want to allow users to submit tags as a list, e.g. ['testing', 'coding', 'python'] instead of requiring them to submit objects - this is because if no tag object exists I'll create one.

How can I do this with tastypie, and it it a violation of REST priniciples?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, except I had both GET and POST use the name instead of the URI.  This might be more internally consistent.

If you just want the POST/PUT to use the name, you should be able to define the [hydrate_tags method of your resource](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#hydrate-foo).  Maybe something like this would work if you were precluded the client from using urls and instead only allow use of names:

```
def hydrate_tags(self, bundle):
    new_list = []
    for item in bundle:
        new_list.append(TagResource.build_bundle(data={name: item.data}))
    return new_list
```

Note that the above is unverified - I didn't check whether hydrate_tags should return a list or a bundle.